# Hilary Putnam's criticism of Carnap's 'Principle of Tolerance'

Tags: logical-positivism, hilary-putnam

I am left quite confused at how Hilary Putnam showed that Carnap's response to the self-defeating objection of the verification principle was circular and hence unviable. Can anybody help explain it to me? Sorry - I am rather new to all this so I would prefer a simple explanation if possible!

Comment: You can see [Hilary Putnam's criticism of Carnap's Principle of Tolerance](https://www.google.com/search?q=Hilary+Putnam%27s+criticism+of+Carnap%27s+Principle+of+Tolerance&oq=Hilary+Putnam%27s+criticism+of+Carnap%27s+Principle+of+Tolerance&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.3107j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active).

Comment: "*Carnap’s defense rests on tolerance, which in turn,rests on verificationism, at least according to Putnam’s interpretation; the defense presupposes that verificationism entails tolerance. But if verificationism is a cognitively meaningless proposal, then it has no entailments and cannot justify tolerance.*" See [Carnap's Pragmatism by Surovel, pp. 79-82](http://d-scholarship.pitt.edu/19799/4/dissertation.pdf).

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for this. I am actually unclear on how tolerance rests on verificationism, however - that's what I wasn't sure about even after reading through a couple times.

Comment: "*Carnap, on Putnam’s reading, grants that verificationism is cognitively meaningless, but emphasizes that it is a practically oriented proposal...  Putnam’s thought is that the claim that the verificationist’s decision to adopt an empiricist language is non-cognitive is a special case of tolerance’s more general thesis that language choice is non-cognitive.*"

Comment: @Conifold I'm not sure I understand this part -  'the verificationist’s decision to adopt an empiricist language **is non-cognitive is a special case of tolerance’s** more general thesis...'.

Comment: You mean what "non-cognitive" means? Carnap tries to save verificationism from being applied to itself (which kills it) by declaring it a "proposal" rather than a truth-apt claim, a.k.a. making it "non-cognitive". Generally, you have to be more specific as to what you do not understand for most informative responses.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry - I should have been clearer. I understand what non-cognitive is and understand what Carnap is trying to do - I also understand that he declares it as a proposal/recommendation to try and avoid that. What i do not understand is the phrasing in '...is non-cognitive i a special case of tolerance'. Other than that sentence not making much sense to me, I want to understand how his principle of 'tolerance' ties into this.

Comment: There is not much here to understand given what the principle of tolerance is: anything goes, subject to pragmatic constraints, in the choice of linguistic frameworks:"*In logic, there are no morals. Everyone is at liberty to build up his own logic, i.e. his own form of language as he wishes*". Verificationism is just an instance of making such a choice.